# How to quit pygame with text input?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to make a screensaver using pygame. I want it to take input from my keyboard, and quit if the correct input is given. This is what i have right now:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT = 768
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
img = pygame.image.load("bilde.jpeg")
running = True
name = ""
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for evt in pygame.event.get():
        if evt.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evt.unicode.isalpha():
                name += evt.unicode
            elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                name = name[:-1]
            elif evt.key == K_RETURN:
                name = ""
            elif evt.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
    if name == "abc":
        running = False
```

in this case i want it to quit if abc is pressed, but nothing happens. (I have added the "K_ESCAPE" event so that i am able to quit while testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not call [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) more than once per frame, otherwise you'll miss some events because this function empties the event queue. Just remove the line `events = pygame.event.get()` and it should work correctly.